# EF Core + Net Core 8 RC2 : GroupBy in a subquery gave an exception on ToList()

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, subquery

This query was working in EF6:

```
 var FamillesNonSaisies = db.CaracsIndivAffichees
     .GroupBy(ci => ci.FamilleCarac).Select(g => new
     {
         Famille = g.Key.Intitule,
         Ordre = g.Key.Ordre,
         Caracs = g.GroupBy(c => c.Parent ?? c, c => new
         {
             c.Id,
             Nom = c.Intitule,
             c.ParentId,
             EstSaisie = false
         })
         .OrderBy(gc => gc.Key.Ordre)
         .ToList()
     }).ToList();

// Classes

 public class FamilleCarac : Model<long>, IItem<long>
 {
     public string Intitule { get; set; }
     public long? ParentId { get; set; }
     public FamilleCarac Parent { get; set; }

     public int? Ordre { get; set; }     
     public ICollection<FamilleCarac> Enfants { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Carac> Caracs { get; set; }
 }

 public class Carac : Model<long>, IItem<long>
 {
    public string Intitule { get; set; }
    public long FamilleCaracId { get; set; }
    public FamilleCarac FamilleCarac { get; set; }

    public int? Ordre { get; set; }
    public long? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Carac Parent { get; set; }
 }

public interface IModel<TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Model<TKey> : IModel<TKey>
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IItem<TKey> : IModel<TKey>
{
    string Intitule { get; }
}
```

Method `CaracsIndivAffichees` returns an `IQueryable` object.

Why did it throw this exception?

> `` ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[Data.Models.Carac,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.TransparentIdentifierFactory+TransparentIdentifier`2[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.TransparentIdentifierFactory+TransparentIdentifier`2[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.TransparentIdentifierFactory+TransparentIdentifier`2[Data.Models.Carac,Data.Models.FamilleCarac],Data.Models.FamilleCarac],Data.Models.Carac]]]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[Data.Models.Carac,<>f__AnonymousType26`3[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int64],System.Boolean]]]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[Data.Models.Carac,<>f__AnonymousType26`3[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int64],System.Boolean]]] AsEnumerable[IGrouping`2](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[Data.Models.Carac,<>f__AnonymousType26`3[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int64],System.Boolean]]])' (Parameter 'arg0') ``

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: @AztecCodes  & Julien: Don't put a single line into a code block, it can't be read except by a small part at a time, scrolling & scrolling. I restored my earlier edit. (I don't care whether it's in block quote.) PS Don't use code format for words that aren't code/messages unless needed to protect literal text.

Comment: And what did you learn from Q&A & the web when you googled 'ArgumentException: Expression of type System.Linq.IQueryable cannot be used for parameter of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com'?

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.